# How to test filesystem in Linux?

Tags: linux

I am planning to test if my linux setup is stable. And I want to test the filesystem of my linux? Is there any standard testing for linux filesystem?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "test the filesystem"? Like stress-test? Integrity test?

Comment: You're looking for `fsck`. And you should ask this on superuser.

Comment: yes this belongs on superuser because as we all know servers don't have filesystems

Comment: A similar question attracted a few answers over on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565865/filesystem-test-suites .

Answer (score 1):

Test how?

If you mean testing that it is correctly installed you may want to run [fsck](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck). Most systems run it at boot time though.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet might be the great [Phoronix test suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[e2fsck](http://linux.die.net/man/8/e2fsck) will check an ext2/ext3 filesystem for metadata integrity. There are similar tools for other filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [bonnie++](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/), a lot of file system developers use it to help measure performance.